# $refs and DOM traversal

Tags: vue.js

I'm using a 3rd party component for my inputs that looks like this:

```html
<base-input
    alternative
    class="mb-3"
    name="Email"
    :rules="{ required: true, email: true }"
    mode="lazy"
    ref="email"
    prepend-icon="ni ni-email-83"
    placeholder="Email"
    v-model="model.email"
>
</base-input>
```

I'm trying to set focus to it.  I researched that you could use this.$refs.email.$el to get the root element.  However this is giving me a SPAN not the INPUT control.

Does Vue have any dom traversing capabilities so I could get the input within the this.$refs.email?

Thank you in a advance.

Comment: Just add @focus="methodName"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the span should contain the input, so this should work

```js
this.$refs.email.$el.querySelector('input').focus();
```

Comment: querySelector is what I was looking for.  thank you.